# Can I still attack with the focus item of Warding Weapon spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, weapons, spell-components

For an upcoming campaign I'm planning on playing a [Magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus). In the Magus spell list the spell *[Warding Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/warding-weapon)* allows a magus to cast spells without provoking AoOs even while not casting defensively. The spell requires a weapon the magus is proficient in as a focus and the description reads:

> Components V, S, F (one melee weapon you are proficient in and you are holding)
>
> The focus of this spell flies upward above your head and takes a defensive position within your space. It lunges at opponents, as if guided by a martially trained hand, parrying and turning back melee attacks aimed at you, but does not strike back at any opponent nor does it damage them. The weapon serves only as a defense. While it protects you, you can cast spells without provoking attacks of opportunity, without the need to cast them defensively. A creature with the Disruptive feat can easily bypass this spell’s defenses. You provoke attacks of opportunity for casting spells against these creatures even when subject to this spell, though you can still choose to cast defensively.

My question is: **Can I still use that same weapon to make melee attacks throughout the duration of the spell?** Nowhere in the spell description does it say that I cannot, and RAW for material components states that focus items are not consumed in casting spells that require them. Will I have to adjust my budget to buy another sword to use for this spell, or is the flavour description just flavour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You are not able to use that weapon for making attacks. The spell clearly states that it leaves your possession to do its job. I suggest you have a backup weapon or one intended to use with this spell. Magus is one of the few magic classes where Quick Draw is beneficial so it doesnt even hurt as much.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted a second opinion on the wording for that particular spell. Usually Paizo is a lot more explicit about what you CAN'T do under certain circumstances, so I expected a more direct "This weapon cannot be used for melee attacks for the duration of the spell" sort of clause.

Comment: Your welcome and no worries. There have been cases where I have pondered similar things.